# Comparing paths (Windows/Linux)

Tags: java, linux, windows, kotlin, path

I would like to see if one of the two paths is inside the other.

What does that mean exactly? I have initially given two paths and I would like to see if one of these two paths points to a folder within the other path.

I thought the easiest way is as follows:

```
path1.startsWith(path2) || path2.startsWith(path1)
```

This code is written in Kotling.

Example:

```
path1 = C:\Users\username\baeldung\bar
patht = C:\Users\username
```

This should return true. If i switch path1 and path2, the result should also be true.

Now the question came to my mind, because I am comparing paths, whether these paths must be canonical and if so, does my method of comparison still work with canonical paths? As far as I know, both paths do not use `..` or `.`.

Because my program should work on Windows and Linux machines and unfortunately I don't know exactly how paths on Linux machines can differ with Windows paths.

Comment: The naive solution is to just split the path by path.separator and compare the resulting arrays, with the caveat that you'll likely need to handle a root portion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Path` class?

```kotlin
/**
 * True if [this] is parent of [other].
 */
fun Path.parentOf(other: Path?): Boolean {
    return if (other == null) {
        false
    } else {
        if (this == other) {
            true
        } else {
            this.parentOf(other.parent)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * True if one of the paths is inside the other.
 */
fun Path.oneInsideTheOther(other: Path): Boolean {
    return this.parentOf(other) || other.parentOf(this)
}

fun main() {
    val path1 = Paths.get("/Users/username/baeldung/bar")
    val path2 = Paths.get("/Users/username")

    println(path1)
    println(path2)
    println(path1.parentOf(path2))
    println(path2.parentOf(path1))

    println(path1.oneInsideTheOther(path2))

    println(path1::class.java)
}
```

Output:

```
/Users/username/baeldung/bar
/Users/username
false
true
true
class sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
```

The `Path` interface has different implementations of different platforms. I'm running Linux, so my implementations are `JrtPath`, `UnixPath` and `ZipPath`, but on Windows, I guess, there will be `WindowsPath` instead of `UnixPath`. So, provided platform-specific string to `Paths.get()` you'll get platform specific `Path` implementation and it's `parent` (the linchpin of this code) will work as intended.